# Is there any better way to do image processing for shadow removal or shadow handling?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, shadow

In attached images, the dark objects are rolling and bouncing on a platform and so, a screenshot is taken at a particular interval. I am able to process the images when there are no shadows, no bouncing and clean background which is a special case. But for following case, other issues come up.

There are two types of images - color and grayscale (different camera settings). And their processed state. So, there are total 4 images to view.

1. stack_color_unprocessed ([stack_color_unprocessed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQyyd.jpg))
2. stack_color_processed ([stack_color_processed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v42eP.jpg))
3. stack_grayscale_unprocessed ([stack_grayscale_unprocessed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2rQf.jpg))
4. stack_grayscale_processed ([stack_grayscale_processed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDVeg.jpg))

Current issues I am tackling

1. color image (shadows, unclean and uneven background, overlapping of shadows causing more darker regions at the top of each object)
2. greyscale image (bouncing leads to darker shadows and the pixel intensity is close to the objects being detected)

I am currently doing image processing with python language and OpenCV and necessary libraries. I am expecting to detect objects (dark color) so that I get closed contour area and then I can find the diameter of the objects.
Calibration used is 4 pixels / mm.

[Original_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GEvS.jpg)

[Expected_or_processed_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn6SN.jpg)

Comment: There are 6 pictures in the question, but none of the lines of code. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.